# Authentication using Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, azure

I have an Azure account and currently a Mobile Service setup with a SQL Database so that my Windows Store app can communicate with the database.

I have developed sites using ASP.NET WebPages authentication. And I need something similar for my Windows Store app.

I have successfully gone through the documentation and tutorials on the Windows Azure website and implemented ACS (Windows Live ID, Google, Yahoo!, and Facebook) - but the thing is - I don't want Google, Yahoo!, Facebook or even Windows Live ID or Microsoft Account) logins - I want my OWN login but it seems that they don't give you this option (correct me if I am wrong).

I need to allow users to signup from within my application (that means, providing their name, DOB, email, phone, address, etc) and shove it all in my database.

Now, after implementing Microsoft Account login with my Azure service, I found out that you can't even get the most basic information about any user who has logged in to your application - not even an email address.

I have spent hours searching online for something that could possibly help but I am running out of keywords - and have not hit a single related result yet.

Does anyone know if this is possible? How would we go about integrating login and signup with a Windows Store app that set/gets this data into/from a Windows Azure service?

Any code, samples, links, tutorials, documentation, etc would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have gone down the road of hooking up external identity authentication, which in my opinion for an external facing web application is a better approach. Benefits are:

- Your application is only responsible for Authorization not Authentication. There is a whole lot of work involved in Authentication and a large number of best practices. Best let those who know best take the burden of this. This doesn't mean you shouldn't try and understand it though.
- If your site gets hacked you don't have to tell them that their username / email and password combo has been compromised and they will probably have to change there passwords on other sits.
- You are also making sure that your users don't have to remember / manage yet another username / email address password combo

If you really want to do the Authentication then that is fine but you will need to do it yourself. Have a look at examples on [Asp.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This is not the only way and nor is it the best way but there are lots of examples.

Now if you decide you want to use external authentication I can give you some pointers to help with your current implementation.

- First thing to note that the Id you get back from Live, Google, Facebook can only be assumed to be unique for that provider. Therefore if you want to keep a profile in your system for that identity and you want to use more than one provider you will need to implement it in such a way that you can keep the id unique in your system and help you associate it with a provider.

[Website Authentication with Social Identity Providers and ACS Part 2 – Integrating ACS with the Universal Profile Provider](http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2013/03/24/152503.aspx)

- As you have found out not all of the Authentication providers return the same "claims". A claim is something that user claims to have, such as an email address, name, date of birth, etc. All the ones you can use by default via the ACS return Uid and some return a name and email address. What you have to do is fill in the gaps. When someone registers you will need to pull the relevant claims and then ask them to fill in the missing ones. You may also want to map the different claims in the ACS to a common name that you can use in your app as one provider might use slightly different names.

[Federated Identity with Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446535.aspx)

- Just because you do not handle Authentication you still need to be responsible for keeping your application secure. Half of the work has been done for you so your code should be a lot lighter but you will still need to make use of roles.

[Windows Azure Role Based authentication (ACS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953277/windows-azure-role-based-authentication-acs)

- The really nice thing about this approach is you can implement your application the same why SO have done with there identity model. You can allow users to associate multiple identities against their profile meaning they can login how they want to.

Comment: Thank you @Bronumski, I definitely do need Roles, which I forgot to mention in my question. I am looking into these and will get back. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you choose not to use the built in providers for `ACS` you will need to implement your own Identity Provider using SAML, OpenId, etc...

You can look into the [`Windows Identity Foundation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) (WIF) for implementing [`WS-Trust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.aspx) or [`WS-Federation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498017.aspx).

There is also [`ADFS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736690.aspx) which has the same set of support but uses Active Directory with WIF and Azure has its own version of AD that can be used.

There is also [`thinktecture identityserver`](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/) which can jumpstart your venture into IdP land, but I have not used it myself yet.

If you want to go the OpenId route there is [`DotNetOpenAuth`](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Comment: Thank you @Romoku, I am looking into these. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to add custom identity to your Mobile Services app, check out Josh's post on custom auth: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx